# Create no more than one record per day

Tags: workflow, validation-rule, record

I want to develop a functionality for creating no more than one record per day. If more than one record is created should show error. How should I do this?

Comment: @AnnappaPH thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: If a question is a duplicate, please flag it as such with the "flag" link above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a Triger to achieve this requirement:

```
trigger createOneRecord on Account(before insert) {
     //Querying data base and checking any account record created on particular day
   List<account> accountList = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE createddate= TODAY]
    //if yes through add error :
   if(accountList.size() > 0)
       trigger.new[0].addError('Create no more than one record per day');
     }else{
   //Do your Logic
  }
```

Check this solution as well

[Salesforce Validation Rule Only Create 1 Record a day](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/125782/salesforce-validation-rule-only-create-1-record-a-day)