# Validation rule for only One record per day

Tags: validation, record

Can anyone help me with a validation rule, which prevents the creation of more than one record per day? I have tried using different Validation rules, but none of them worked as expected. I know this question has been answered many times, but none of the answers were helpful for me.

Comment: You cannot do this with validation rule, you will need to write an Apex trigger for this.

Comment: @rahulgawale can you help me with the apex code, and where to use the apex code?

Comment: Find in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/125782/salesforce-validation-rule-only-create-1-record-a-day) post, an answer by Tushar Sharma

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with validation rule, Either you need to write an Apex trigger or you need to set up a process builder and call an apex class from that process.

Sample Code:

```
Public static beforeinsertHandler(List<Sobjectname> Records)
{
LIST details=[Select id from sobject where createddate=TODAY LIMIT 1];
If(For sobjectiterator: records)
{
If(details <> null && !details.isEmpty())
{
sobjectiterator.addError('Error message');
}
}
}
```

For Refernce:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/

Comment: I think you mean `WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY`. If you use `=:System.Today()` I believe you are looking for an exact datetime match down to the millisecond....

Comment: Nope it will return only today's date

Comment: `details <> null` unnecessary... the variable will never be null.

Comment: Good catch but usually I write as a precaution

Comment: TODAY and System.Today() are different, try it for yourself. `System.debug('System.today() :  + [SELECT Id FROM Asset WHERE LastModifiedDate = :System.today()]);
System.debug('TODAY : ' + [SELECT Id FROM Asset WHERE LastModifiedDate = TODAY]);`  Prints out `System.today() : ()` and `TODAY : (Asset:{Id=02i3B000003rhL8QAI, RecordTypeId=0123B0000005uztQAA})`

Answer (score 1):

A validation rule would only work in conjunction with another object which will store the last date at which the last record was inserted. This would be very clunky and computationally expensive to implement.

A cleaner solution would be to implement this in a trigger before insert.

```
class CustomObjectTriggerHandler {

public void beforeInsert(List<Custom_Object__c> newList) {
    List<Custom_Object__c> mostRecentlyCreatedRecord = new List<Custom_Object__c>(
    [SELECT Id FROM Custom_Object__c WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY LIMIT 1]
    );
    if (!mostRecentlyCreatedRecord.isEmpty()) {
        for (Custom_Object__c obj : newList) {
            obj.addError('Only one can be created per day');
        }
    }
}
```